# wix xsl transform to conditionally remove components

Tags: xslt, wix

I'm creating a transform for WiX's heat utility that needs to suppress the harvesting of folders matching a specific name (.PayloadData) under the tree being harvested.

I can easily get it to suppress the Directory and Component elements but the ComponentRef element is proving tricky.

The folder is called .PayloadData and this successfully suppresses the Directory and Component elements:

```
  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.PayloadData']" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.PayloadData']/*" />
```

I tried something similar for the ComponentRef element but it matches everything.

```
<xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[//wix:Directory[@Name='.PayloadData']/wix:Component[@Id=@Id]]">
```

I think @Id might be ambiguous in the xpath expression but I don't know how to tell it that the ComponentRef's Id attribute is trying to match the Component's Id attribute.

Here's the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include $(var.ProjectDir)\..\Common\Common.wxi?>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleDataDir">
            <Directory Id="dirFD22039A64AC1D31F568C1632B5AF8A3" Name=".PayloadData">
                <Component Id="cmp846A29F6413B27E8777DD68E6026E461" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil9227EFCE377E7FEBB63A4BD121F278AE" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\.PayloadData\SampleData.xml" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="dirA4E41FB410D214A14F0C8A302E5E70D2" Name="AlternativePBS">
                <Component Id="cmp3E04EEF702FDD121FD225ABF32550EDB" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filF1367714C6CE3472899C32E78D3D6D0C" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\01-ADMIN_Update_PBSHierarchy.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp6732C6415C5574DB586333DE13FAFD1C" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil7F1A16AA0DA338664312C832796DD228" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\02-SCHEMA_Update_PBSHierarchy.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp01BD73A317794376E5323FA329D1BFEB" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filFD2213EB9E67560F25B506695650F7B0" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\ProcedureForAltPBSStructure.doc" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp1E93AAFF75E01670D20E84280E7B9B5C" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filC02D64539D33E6B5250C883EFF6357DD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\SPFAdapter_PBS.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp428BA2587DEE28B22239181E175B108B" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil8D32FED82C161537AE2432BFA7F89310" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\UpdatePBSHierarchyGraphDef.xmlldr" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="CG_SampleData">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp846A29F6413B27E8777DD68E6026E461" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp3E04EEF702FDD121FD225ABF32550EDB" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp6732C6415C5574DB586333DE13FAFD1C" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp01BD73A317794376E5323FA329D1BFEB" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp1E93AAFF75E01670D20E84280E7B9B5C" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp428BA2587DEE28B22239181E175B108B" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And this is the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include $(var.ProjectDir)\..\Common\Common.wxi?>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="SampleDataDir">
            <Directory Id="dirA4E41FB410D214A14F0C8A302E5E70D2" Name="AlternativePBS">
                <Component Id="cmp3E04EEF702FDD121FD225ABF32550EDB" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filF1367714C6CE3472899C32E78D3D6D0C" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\01-ADMIN_Update_PBSHierarchy.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp6732C6415C5574DB586333DE13FAFD1C" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil7F1A16AA0DA338664312C832796DD228" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\02-SCHEMA_Update_PBSHierarchy.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp01BD73A317794376E5323FA329D1BFEB" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filFD2213EB9E67560F25B506695650F7B0" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\ProcedureForAltPBSStructure.doc" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp1E93AAFF75E01670D20E84280E7B9B5C" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="filC02D64539D33E6B5250C883EFF6357DD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\SPFAdapter_PBS.xml" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp428BA2587DEE28B22239181E175B108B" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="fil8D32FED82C161537AE2432BFA7F89310" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SampleDataDir)\AlternativePBS\UpdatePBSHierarchyGraphDef.xmlldr" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="CG_SampleData">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp3E04EEF702FDD121FD225ABF32550EDB" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp6732C6415C5574DB586333DE13FAFD1C" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp01BD73A317794376E5323FA329D1BFEB" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp1E93AAFF75E01670D20E84280E7B9B5C" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp428BA2587DEE28B22239181E175B108B" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

It needs to strip out:

- Directory dirFD22039A64AC1D31F568C1632B5AF8A3
- Component cmp846A29F6413B27E8777DD68E6026E461
- ComponentRef cmp846A29F6413B27E8777DD68E6026E461

Comment: Do you know what `//` means?

Comment: You will probably get help sooner if you add an example of an input document into the question.

Comment: Yes, // means search the entire document.  
I'll post the sample documents shortly.  I need a before and intended result document.  For those that don't know, heat applies the transform in memory so I don't get the before document unless I remove my transform from the flow.

Comment: "*Yes, // means search the entire document.*" Exactly. So if the condition is true, it will be true for **all**l `ComponentRef` nodes.

Comment: P.S. If you need to match the `ComponentRef` and `Component` based on common `id`, define and use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key).

Comment: Cheers!  I'll look into using a key.
Also, part of the problem is the Directory element can be nested below other Directory elements making it impossible to give a specific path to the element (absolute or relative).  The sample input is just a sample, I have others where the .PayloadData directory is located multiple times in different places.

Comment: Then what exactly is the condition, in terms of logic? You can easily test if one of the **ancestor** directories has a specific name. If it's something else, you need to elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help.  I now have the answer.  Key was the key (pun intended):

```
  <xsl:key name="ComponentsToSuppress" match="wix:Component[ancestor::wix:Directory[@Name='.PayloadData']]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='.PayloadData']" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('ComponentsToSuppress', @Id)]" />
```

This allows me to suppress the Component and ComponentRef of items appearing under a Directory named ".PayloadData" regardless of where it appears (or how often it appears).

Comment: I believe your 2nd template is redundant. Also. `//` doesn't do anything in a match pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  I was thinking about it after I'd posted it.  I'll try it to make sure it doesn't change the outcome and update the answer accordingly.